# Room:362 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm using ajax to post form's data, But i have an error when i click on submit button. it seems that Ajax consider a null value for `#img1`. And doesn't send the file input value to the action.

---

error message in *inspect element*:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>     at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (Room:403)
>     at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
>     at HTMLDocument.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
> ```

Ajax Codes:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitTheRoom', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var FileUpload = $("#img1").get(0);
        var Files = FileUpload.Files;

        var Data = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < Files.length; i++) {
            Data.append('img1', Files[i]);
        }
        $('input, select').each(function (x,y) {
            Data.append($(y).attr('name'), $(y).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddEditRoom", "Room", new { area = "Admin"})',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: Data
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status === "success") {
                alert(res.message);
            } else {
                alert("در ثبت اطلاعات مشکلی بوجود آمده. لطفا دوباره تلاش کنید");
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, b, error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    })
```

My form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<input asp-for="Id" class="form-control hidden formInput" />

    <div class="form-group myFormGroup col-lg-6  col-md-12">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 control-label formLabel"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 myInputContainer">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control formInput" />
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger myError"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group myFormGroup col-lg-6  col-md-12">
        <label asp-for="Explanation" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 control-label formLabel"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 myInputContainer">
            <input asp-for="Explanation" class="form-control formInput" />
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Explanation" class="text-danger myError"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group myFormGroup col-lg-6  col-md-12">
        <label asp-for="RoomImageOne" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 control-label formLabel"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 myInputContainer">
            <input id="img1" name="img1" type="file" 
                class="form-control formInput" asp-for="RoomImageOne" />
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="RoomImageOne" class="text-danger myError"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="button" id="submitTheRoom" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, I'll delete after.

Comment-out your js and test with this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitTheRoom', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var FileUpload = $("#img1").get(0);
    console.log("FileUpload: " + FileUpload);

    var Files = FileUpload.files;                 // lower case f.
    console.log("Files: " + Files);               // [object FileList]
    console.log("Files.length: " + Files.length); // should be 0 on first load.
});
```

Are you getting the same results? Different?

Add this to your original question and add comments there, not here. I'll delete this if it's of no use.

Comment: The problem was two things: 1. 'Files' most be lower case and 2. Input's name and id most be same as the value you are using in ajax (i mean 'files' in third line of my ajax codes)

Comment: yes!! jquery  `$` was not working only in this case among all other places I've used at, but `document.getElementById` worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
var Files = FileUpload.Files;
```

is returning undefined. Check the value of the FileUpload on the console and see if FileUpload.Files returns anything. Try

```
var Files = FileUpload.files;
```

instead. I suspect the upper case might be a typo

Comment: I checked value of the FileUpload in console. It was a button tag with (type="file" , id="img1" , name="img1") attributes. Also i tried FileUpload.files. it doesn't change anything. What should i do?

Comment: so the `FileUpload.Files` is okay?

Comment: okay i actually thought the uppercase`FileUpload.Files` was a typo and should instead be `FileUpload.files`

Comment: You welcome. Please update post with what you did to solve so that others coming later can benefit

Comment: I commented that in the second answer by @wazz